# putmerge of hadoop in action is not working

Tags: hadoop

I was trying to compile the putmerge program of hadoop in action from eclipse but it not not working instead of creating a file on HDFS it is creating the file on my localmachine(where i have install eclipse).

Its look like my conf are not picking correct configuration from XML files.

EDIT:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

public class PlayWithHadoop {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
//conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser");
//conf.set("dfs.data.dir", "/user/hduser");
conf.addResource(new Path("/home/hduser/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path("/home/hduser/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));

FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);
FileSystem local = FileSystem.getLocal(conf);
Path inputDir = new Path(args[0]);
Path hdfsFile = new Path(args[1]);

try {
//hdfs.setWorkingDirectory(new Path("/user/hduser/hadoop"));
FileStatus[] inputFiles = local.listStatus(inputDir);
FSDataOutputStream out = hdfs.create(hdfsFile);

for (int i=0; i<inputFiles.length; i++) {
System.out.println(inputFiles[i].getPath().getName());
FSDataInputStream in =local.open(inputFiles[i].getPath());
System.out.println();
System.out.println(hdfs.getWorkingDirectory().toString());


byte buffer[] = new byte[256];
int bytesRead = 0;
while( (bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
in.close();
}
out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines in your code and see if it works :

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.addResource(new Path("/HADOOP_HOME/conf/core-site.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path("/HADOOP_HOME/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply , I added these option but in another way like conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser"); But when i am using the System.out.println(hdfs.getWorkingDirectory().toString());
it is showing hdfs://localhost:54310/user/mohit
ideally it should show hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser

Comment: this one is different from the properties I have specified. it tells you the address of your NN and the properties i have shown tells your code where to get the config files to pick up the config parameters. if you don't add "fs.default.name", your code will still work, IMHO

Comment: I did as you have mentioned conf.addResource(new Path("/home/hduser/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path("/home/hduser/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
but still getting hdfs://localhost:54310/user/mohit
it should be hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser

Comment: it is not showing any error . code went thru fine . problem is ideally as per the logic of code it should create a file on HDFS but it is creating file on my local(eclipse workspace) location.

Comment: somehow i figure it out. In my HDFS i have 3 user but when i do hadoop fs -ls it only shows /user/hduser/ dont knw why.Let me know how to change this to /user/{some other user}

Comment: i'm sorry for the late response. you could d o that using : bin/hadoop fs -chown [-R] [OWNER][:[GROUP]] URI [URI ]

Comment: Hi Tariq, chown is used to assign a group or change the user permission but my problem here is when i am doing hadoop fs -ls it is showing all the dir/files of /usr/hduser but when i am doing some operation from the eclipse it will try to do everything in /usr/mohit. now i want from eclipse to do the operation on /usr/hduser instead of /usr/mohit

Answer (score 0):

// Try this code and see that you give input, outpath path correctly for the jar.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.permission.FsPermission;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.FloatWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Progressable;

/**
 *
 * @author hadoop1
 */
public class PutMerge {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        //Configuration would be taking the resource that contains set of name/value pairs as XML
        //Since Configuration automatically loads the properties from core-site.xml in its constructor, and core-site.xml should contain fs.defaultFS,
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        //FIleSystem Abstract class is used to get the conf key to connect to HDFS
        //FileSystem needs only one configuration key to successfully connect to HDFS. Previously it was fs.default.name. 
        //From yarn onward it's changed to fs.defaultFS. So the following snippet is sufficient for the connection. 
        FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        //For local connection l
        FileSystem local = FileSystem.getLocal(conf);

        Path inputDirectory = new Path(args[0]);
        Path hdfsFiles = new Path(args[1]);

        try {

            FileStatus[] inputFiles = local.listStatus(inputDirectory);
            FSDataOutputStream out = hdfs.create(hdfsFiles);

            for (int i = 0; i < inputFiles.length; i++) {
                //System.out.println(inputFiles[i].getPath().getName());

                FSDataInputStream in = local.open(inputFiles[i].getPath());
                byte buffer[] = new byte[256];
                int byteRead = 0;

                while ((byteRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, byteRead);
                }
                in.close();
            }
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("We have an error");
        }

        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "PutMerge");
        job.setJarByClass(PutMerge.class);
        job.setMapperClass(PutMergeMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(PutMergeReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(PutMergeReducer.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(FloatWritable.class);


        // HDFS path will contain the merged files
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, hdfsFiles);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));

        try {

            // For the job to wait unless one part of job is over
            System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)? 0 : 1);
            //To take the input path of multiple csvs
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.print("Error 1 in main file %^#%$^&*(&&$%^&*(*^&%");
        }
    }
}
```